# JS Tabulator row icon pop-up menu

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Using [JS Tabulator](http://www.tabulator.info/), this is what I have so far:
[image]

I'm looking to build a feature with [JS Tabulator](http://www.tabulator.info/), which allows for row mover icon to be used as a button to show the menu. I've seen this accomplished by https://www.notion.so as they have rows with pop up menu, like so:

[image]

This allows for rows to be moved (by holding left click and moving the mouse) or to just click on the icon and menu shows up.

How can I get the menu to show in Tabulator and then show the pop-up menu it's self. My guess would be to add click handler on the icon (not sure how to do that) and then show menu (probably using some library).

If you have any further questions, please ask and thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I believe [Context Menu](https://github.com/s-yadav/contextMenu.js) is the library used, with lots of styling done to it. Hope that's helpful to someone.